# which of the following closest approximation to the length, in inches , of a side of that square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a rectangle with width 49.872 inches and length 30.64 inches has a area that is 15 times the area of the certain square , which of the following closest approximation to the length, in inches , of a side of that square ?

```
1) 5 
2) 10 
3) 15 
4) 20 
5) 25
```

Comment: Can you first determine the area of said rectangle? Once you do that, can you determine the area of our desired square? How can you determine the side length of said square given this area?

Comment: that what i am trying search , how i can find it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A_R = \operatorname{Area}_{\text{Rectangle}} = \text{Length}\;\times\;\text{Width} \approx 50 \times 30  =  1500$$

$$S_A = \operatorname{Area}_{\text{Square}} = \frac{1}{15} \times R_A \approx 1500 = 100$$
since $R_A = 15\times S_A \iff S_A = \dfrac 1{15}R_A$.

$$S_L \approx \sqrt{S_A} \approx \sqrt{100} \approx \;\;?$$

Where $S_L$ denotes the length of the side of the desired square.

Comment: i think must be 10

Comment: Yes, indeed, does that make sense? Can you see how, since we are looking for approximations, we can do some rounding to make the computations easier?

Comment: I am not understanding why we are taking squareroot  of area of square. √≈100−−−√  In problem they didn't asked to squareroot

Comment: Because the area of the square is (side length)$^2$, so the side length is the square root of the area.  If a side length is length $10$, it's area is $10^2$. If the area is $100$, the side length is $\sqrt{100}$ since $\sqrt{100}\times \sqrt{100} = 10 \times 10 = 100$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes sure , Really appropriated the way you explained!

Comment: You're welcome, SSK ;-)

Comment: Got it, SSK! $~~~~~$

Comment: @amWhy: very nice! Just got to my hotel for my talk tomorrow and I feel warped! Hope you had a great day! +1

Answer (score 0):

The area of the rectangle ($A_R$) is:
$$A_R =L\times W =(30.64)(49.872)\approx 1497.4$$
Since the area of the rectangle is 15 times the area of the square ($A_S)$, we have:
$$A_S=\frac{A_R}{15}\approx\frac{1497.4}{15}\approx 99.8$$
Now, the area of a square is equal to its side length squared, so we have:
$$\text{Side of the square}\approx\sqrt{99.8}\approx 10$$
So the closest approximation for the side length is $10$ inches.

Comment: can you explain me , how you determined side length squared ?

Comment: The side length squared is the area of the square. We were given that the area of the square is one fifteenth of the area of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Find the area of rectangle.
Area=length*width
now 15*(area of square)=area of rectangle
and
area of square=(side)^2

then you get desired answer

area of rectangle = 1582.07808

thus area of square=1582.07808/15 = 101.871872

thus length of side = approximately 10